# When could a CSV records *not* have the same number of fields?

Tags: csv

I am storing a series of **events** to a CSV file, each **event type** comes with a **different set of data**.

To illustrate, say I have two events (there will be many more):

1. **Running**, which has a data set containing *speed* and *incline*.
2. **Sleeping**,  which has a data set containing *snores*.

There are two options to store this data in CSV records:

**Option A**

Storing each possible item of data in it's own field...

```
speed, incline, snores
```

*therefore...*

```
15mph, 20%, ,
, , 12
16mph, 20%, ,
14mph, 20%, ,
```

**Option B**

Storing each event in its own record...

```
event, value1...
```

*therefore...*

```
running, 15mph, 20%
sleeping, 12
running, 16mph, 20%
running, 14mph, 20%
```

Without a specific CSV specification, the [consensus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Toward_standardization) seems to be:

> Each record "should" contain the same number of comma-separated fields.

**Context**

- There are a number of events which each have a large & different set of data values.
- CSV data is to be of use to other developers (I will/could/should/won't use either structure).
- The 'other developers' to be toward the novice end of the spectrum and/or using resource limited systems. CSV is accessible.
- The CSV format is being provided non-exclusively as feature not requirement. Although, if said application is providing a CSV file it should be provided in the correct manner from now on.

**Question**

Would it be valid – in this case - to go with Option B?

**Thoughts**

Option B maintains a level of human readability, which is an advantage say CSV is read by human not processor. Neither method is more complex to parse using a custom parser, but will Option B void the usefulness of a CSV format with other libraries, frameworks, applications et al. With Option A future changes/versions to the data set of an individual event may break the CSV structure (zombie `, ,` to maintain forwards compatibility); whereas Option B will fail gracefully.

**edit**

This may be aimed at students and frameworks like OpenFrameworks, Plask, Proccessing et al. where CSV *is* easier to implement.

Comment: It depends on who and how will later parse it.

Comment: @Andrey, please see the context as a use case.

Comment: @JayRiggs 1 is also the typo.

Comment: Option B, each record is self contained and adding new record types will not affect existing ones, although each record type should be consistent,

Comment: Why not have two CSV files (and a sequence or timestamp column, to preserver relative ordering)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any "other frameworks, libraries and applications" I've ever used all handle CSV parsing differently, so trying to conform to one or many of these standards might over-complicate your end result.  My recommendation would be to keep it simple and use what works for your specific task.  If human readbility is a requirement, then CSV in the form of Option B would work fine.  Otherwise, you may want to consider JSON or XML.

Answer (score 1):

As you say there is no "CSV Standard" with regard to contents.  The real answer depend on what you are doing and why. You mention "other frameworks, libraries and applications". The one thing I've learnt is "Dont over engineer". i.e. Don't write reams of code today on the assumption that you will plug it into some other framework tomorrow.

I'd say option B is fine, unless you have specific requirements to use other apps etc.

< edit >

Having re-read your context, I'd probably pick one output format and use it, and forget about having multiple formats:

- Having multiple output formats is a source of inconsistency (e.g. bug in one format but not another).
- Having multiple formats means more code that needs to be

  - tested
  - documented
  - supported

< /edit >

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you can't use XML?  Yes, it's slightly more difficult to parse, at least for novices, but if so they probably need the practice.  File size would be much greater, of course, but it's compressible.

Comment: Providing XML and JSON also. Also XML etc can be heavy/complex on a microprocessor.